# Create Controller Service using Nifi API REST

Tags: api, apache-nifi

I am trying to create a controller service using nifi api rest but I am blocked because when I try:

InvokeHTTP
POST
https://hostname/nifi-api/controller/controller-services

using this json

```
{
  "revision": {
    "version": 0
  },
  "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged": false,
  "component": {
    "name": "DMCS_try",
    "type": "org.apache.nifi.distributed.cache.server.map.DistributedMapCacheServer",
    "bundle": {
      "group": "org.apache.nifi",
      "artifact": "nifi-distributed-cache-services-nar",
      "version": "1.9.0.3.4.1.1-4"
    },
    "state": "ENABLED",
    "properties": {
      "Port": "4555",
      "Maximum Cache Entries": "10000",
      "Eviction Strategy": null,
      "Persistence Directory": null,
      "SSL Context Service": null
    }
}
}
```

I got this "error"

```
Node XXXXXXXXX is unable to fulfill this request due to: Unable to modify the controller. Contact the system administrator. Contact the system administrator.
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller services can be created in two different places. One place is in the flow as part of a process group so they can be used by processors, the other place is at the controller level for use by reporting tasks.

The URL you specified is for creating a service at the controller level and therefore whatever identity you are using to authenticate as need permissions to modify the controller (WRITE on /controller). The error message is saying you don't have that permission.

Comment: Hi Bryan,

Thanks for you answer. Do you know if there is a way to create the controller service using nifi api rest?

Comment: Everything you can do in the UI you can do with REST. One common technique is to open a Developer Console in your browser and add a Controller Service through the UI, then note the REST calls being made. You can then do the same thing with curl, an app, etc.